# Alfresco 3.4 Directory Tree View

Tags: user-interface, alfresco

I'm building a custom dialog in Alfresco 3.4.  I'd like to include a tree view as a UI control similar to the one in the Copy/Move dialog in the Document Library.  Is there a call in Alfresco or an easy way to include this to drive my dialog, or is this going to be a completely custom piece?

Comment: I've found the DocListTree component but not sure how to implement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to write your custom tree view as far as I know. But including the one that Share uses is not that easy as well, unless you have experience with webscripts, building custom pages, templates...

First check these out:

http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Share_Custom_Pages

http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/3.0_Component_Standards

---

### Here's where the files that you need to look at are located

The client side javascript files that Share uses are here:

```
tomcat/webapps/share/components/documentlibrary/
```

---

Look at the following files: tree.js, repo-tree.js or dod5015-tree.js (RM implementation)

---

The share webscripts are here:

```
tomcat/webapps/share/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/site-webscripts/org/alfresco/components/documentlibrary
```

Look at the following files: tree.get.*, repo-tree.get.*, dod5015-tree.get.*

---

Here's how the tree component is included in document library:

```
tomcat/webapps/share/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/site-data/template-instances/documentlibrary.xml
```

Comment: I ended up recreating the Tree View due to some other requirements, but the files you outlined really helped get me on the right track.  Thank you!

Comment: I have implemented document library view in custom page. I am getting result in api bit not diaplaying.